# Access VBA Mass text file import Run time error 3310

Tags: vba, ms-access, text, import

I have written Access VBA code which imports text files.  (Several different vba modules which are directed at different file paths.  However, when it gets to 5500-6000 cumulative files processed, it stops and gives the following error:

[image]

In order to begin importing again, a restart of Access is required.  I have tried adding a "DoEvents", but that does not seem to do much.  I have researched online and see that others have had the same issue, but am unable to find an answer to what they did.  Does anyone know how to get around what seems to be Access's limit on the number of files it can import in one sitting?

Code excerpt:  Where it stops is in bold.

```
If FileExists(ImportFileName) = True Then
    **DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, ImportSpecification, ImportTable, ImportPath & ImportFile, False, ""**

Else
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO " & FNFTable & " (FundID, IndexID, FileName) VALUES (" & FundID & ", " & IndexID & ", '" & ImportFile & "');"
    FNFResults = FNFResults + 1
    GoTo NextTimePeriod:
End If
```

Comment: This suggests one of the files may be an issue. Just before the TransferText call, add `Debug.Print ImportFileName`. Now re-run entire process and when it errs check the last entry written in Intermediate Window of VBA IDE. Open that text file and check its content.

Comment: At first, I thought it was limited to a specific file too, but it isn't.  It will stop randomly on any file after the combined programs run about 6000 files.  If I restart access and run the program that had the problem again, it imports everything as expected.

Comment: Then, break up your looping into batches of 500 or 1,000 files. You might be hitting a memory/resource limit. So uninitialize/re-initialize VBA objects between batches.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not explaining correctly.  I have 8 different subs.  They run individually based on user selection of what to import.  Each sub imports anywhere from 400 files to 4500 files based on which sub is selected to run.  At some point, sub A + Sub B + Sub C, etc is going to exceed this file limit.  Would you please explain a bit more about the uninitialize/re-initialize VBA object that I can try implementing between subs?  Thank you.

Comment: Please post more of your code to show full extent of subroutines and how they are triggered. Even describe the content of the files. Are users simultaneously writing to same tables?

Comment: After further research, I find it is just an Access limitation that I can't prevent.  However, I can program around it.  I added error handling code that captures the loop where the limit is hit (x) and the program name that is running at that time.  From there, I added a message that tells the user to restart access.  Upon restart, a Resume Import button shows on the main menu that allows the user to click that and the program will run from where it left off.  Thank you, Parfait, for your insight.